# Fsync too fast?

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems

I'm surprised about big file `ftruncate` and `fsync` operations. I wrote a program that create an empty file on a Linux 64 bits system, truncate it to 0xffffffff bytes and after, `fsync` it.

After all operations, file is correctly created with this length.

I see that `ftruncate` cost about 1442 microseconds and `fsync` cost only 4 microseconds.

Is normal this high performance? Are really wrotten all bytes on disc? If not, how can I ensure this sync?

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

static const size_t __tamFile__ = 0xffffffff;

int main(int, char **)
{
    std::string fichero("./testTruncate.dat");

    unlink(fichero.c_str());

    int fd = open(fichero.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        struct timeval t1, t2;

        timerclear(&t1);
        timerclear(&t2);

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
        ftruncate(fd, __tamFile__);
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

        unsigned long long msecTruncate = static_cast<unsigned long long>((((t2.tv_sec * 1E6) + t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec * 1E6) + t1.tv_usec))) ;

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
        fdatasync(fd);
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

        unsigned long long msecFsync = static_cast<unsigned long long>((((t2.tv_sec * 1E6) + t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec * 1E6) + t1.tv_usec))) ;

        std::cout << "Total microsec truncate: " << msecTruncate << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total microsec fsync: " << msecFsync << std::endl;

        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wrote a program that create an empty file on a Linux 64 bits system,
>   truncate it to 0xffffffff bytes and after, fsync it.

Unless you write something to it, it's extremely possible the file contains holes.

From TLPI:

> What happens if a program seeks past the end of a file, and then
>   performs I/O? A call to read() will return 0, indicating end-of-file.
>   Somewhat surprisingly, it is possible to write bytes at an arbitrary
>   point past the end of the file.
>
> The space in between the previous end
>   of the file and the newly written bytes is referred to as a file hole.
>   From a programming point of view, the bytes in a hole exist, and
>   reading from the hole returns a buffer of bytes containing 0 (null
>   bytes).
>
> File holes don’t, however, take up any disk space. The file
>   system doesn’t allocate any disk blocks for a hole until, at some
>   later point, data is written into it.

Comment: Maybe one should also mention, that this feature is commonly referred to as sparse files (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

Comment: If you want space to actually be reserved for all those zero bytes, you need to call `posix_fallocate` on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Which Linux kernel version do you have, which filesystem, and which mount options (in particular, are barriers enabled?)?

On Linux 2.6.32 64-bit, ext4 with barriers enabled (the default), I get

```
$ ~/src/cpptest/truncsync 
Total microsec truncate: 32
Total microsec fsync: 266
Total microsec close: 14
```

Otherwise the same, but with a NFS mounted filesystem, I get

```
$ ./truncsync 
Total microsec truncate: 38297
Total microsec fsync: 6
Total microsec close: 6
$ ./truncsync 
Total microsec truncate: 3454967
Total microsec fsync: 8
Total microsec close: 330
```

Comment: Is a Linux 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP mounting a nfs AIX filesystem mounted against a jfs2 filesystem. No special mount options. I have no idea about barries configuration.